# Python tkiner, two text boxes with x and y scrollbars for both

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to make a gui that has two separate text outputs with horizontal and vertical scollbars for each text box that are fixed to the right and bottom edges of each respective text windows. I am struggling with how to do this with the tkinter grid and any help would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk


class WeatherGUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)


        # Horizontal (x) Scroll bar
        self.xscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.xscrollbar.grid(column=5, row=10, sticky="we")

        # Vertical (y) Scroll Bar
        self.yscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.yscrollbar.grid(column=5, row=10, sticky='ns')

        self.xscrollbar2 = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal")
        self.xscrollbar2.grid(column=9, row=10, sticky="we")

        # Vertical (y) Scroll Bar
        self.yscrollbar2 = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        self.yscrollbar2.grid(column=9, row=10, sticky='ns')


        self.NSW_actual_text = tk.Text(self, width=50, wrap = "none", xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set,)
        self.NSW_actual_text.grid(column=0, columnspan=4, row= 8,padx=(20, 10))

        self.NSW_forecast_text = tk.Text(self, width=50, wrap = "none", xscrollcommand=self.xscrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.yscrollbar.set)
        self.NSW_forecast_text.grid(column=8, columnspan=4, row= 8,padx=(20, 10))

        self.xscrollbar.config(command=self.NSW_actual_text.xview)
        self.yscrollbar.config(command=self.NSW_actual_text.yview)


        self.xscrollbar2.config(command=self.NSW_forecast_text.xview)
        self.yscrollbar2.config(command=self.NSW_forecast_text.yview)



        self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="Generate NWS Actual", command=self.GenerateNWSActual)
        self.btn1.grid(column=1, row=0)


        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Generate NWS Forecast", command=self.GenerateNWSForecast)
        self.btn2.grid(column=10, row=0)


    def GenerateNWSActual(self):
        self.NSW_actual_text.insert('1.0', "This is where actual weather would go")


    def GenerateNWSForecast(self):
        self.NSW_forecast_text.insert('1.0', "this is where forecast weather would go")




app = WeatherGUI()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your example would be better if you removed the dependency on the external modules. If the question is about how to arrange two sets of widgets and scrollbars, the other modules are irrelevant.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Should I delete this question and as a more focused one?

Comment: If the textbox is at (row,col), then put the vertical scrollbar to (row,col+1) and the horizontal scrollbar to (row+1, col) with same columnspan value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example allows you to attach two functional scrollbars (x, y) to a Text widget

```
from tkinter import *
# Create Window
root = Tk()
# Create ScrollBars
xScrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL) 
yScrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient=VERTICAL)
# Create Text Widget with scroll commands
TextWidget = Text(root, xscrollcommand=xScrollbar, yscrollcommand=yScrollbar)
# Package Componets
xScrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
yScrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
TextWidget.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=20)
# Assign Scrollbars with TextWidget
xScollbar.config(command=TextWidget.xview)
yScollbar.config(command=TextWidget.yview)
```

You can use this examble for both of your TextWidgets in your weather application.